# For loop to run all sql files in a directory with variables that come from an R script

Tags: r, batch-file, for-loop

I'd like to use a for loop in a batch file to run all the sql files in a folder.

I've seen this loop in a previous Stack Overflow question

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S servername /d databaseName -E -i"%%G"
pause
```

How could I make that work with a batch command like this:

```
sqlcmd -S servername -d databasename -v Var1=%var1% Var2=%var2% -i "[PATH]\query.sql"
pause
```

How can I add variables to the for loop but also how do I direct `%%G` to the correct path?

Would this work?

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S servername /d databaseName -E -v Var1=%var1% Var2=%var2% -i"%%G"
pause
```

Comment: Where is `R script` relevant? If your last command needs a path for `%%G` change to `%%~fG` See `Help for`

Comment: @LotPings the R script is completely irrelevant to this question. I only mentioned it to explain where `%var1%` and `%var2%` came from.

Comment: @LotPings but how do I input a path into `%%~fG`?

Comment: You don't have to. The for loop processes the wildcard and the modifier `~f`` forces the full path to be returned. **See Help for or For /? in a cmd console**

Comment: @LotPings okay let me rephrase. If this query is executed in a different directory than where the .sql files are located, how do I point it towards a specific directory where these .sql files are at? If I have two directories with .sql files and want to run both at different times, how could I differentiate? Do I just need to put a `cd` command before the for loop runs?

Comment: Include the absolute or relative path in the for `for %%G in ("X:\path\to\*.sql)` or `for %%G in ("..\path\*.sql")`

Comment: @Sorry for late reply, when I put the full path in, the command line tells me: `The system cannot find the file ..\path\*.sql` (I put the actual full path link in there, but I'm just copying your format).

Comment: I don't know wether sqlcmd nor it's options - you don't know batch. I suggest you learn more about batch on http://ss64.com/nt